# Does DIBAL-H reduce alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, organic-reduction

Does DIBAL-H reduce alcohol? I was reading an article by Rentsch and Kalesse [[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201206560)] and I came across this reaction, but could not figure out how the final compound is formed:

> [image: Synthesis of 4]

#### Reference

1. Rentsch, A.; Kalesse, M. The Total Synthesis of Corallopyronin A and Myxopyronin B. *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2012**, 51 (45), 11381–11384. DOI: [10.1002/anie.201206560](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201206560).

Comment: Dibal-H is reducing the ester to the allylic alcohol which is oxidised to the aldehyde by Manganese Dioxide.

Comment: The highlighting in your image seems to suggest you are stuck on a different step (c) than the DIBAl-H reduction (d). Could you clarify which step you are stuck on: (c) or (d)? If you understand (a) and (b), what do you think the structure is after (b)?

Comment: i understand step (a) follows The Mitsunobu reaction, and steps (d) and (e) gives the aldehyde moiety in the final product, im stuck on how the C=C is formed in steps (b) and (c), the article says sulfer is oxidized to sulfone.Then, KHMDS deprotonate the carbon next to the sulfur and reacted with acetaldehyde

Comment: thank you, i guess im not understanding how the C=C is formed then and what would be the structure of step (b) and (c)

Comment: For the early steps, look at the Julia Olefination reaction: https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/modified-julia-kocienski-olefination.shtm